# Getting 404 HTTP Errors for ~/Script content using Babaganoush

Tags: babaganoush-sitefinity

I have a vanilla install of Sitefinity 7.1.5200 and I added Bababanoush to the web project. When I view the home page (the only basic page of the site), I am getting the following ~/Scripts errors:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /MobMediaStudiosSite/Scripts/baseurl
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /MobMediaStudiosSite/Scripts/basescriptsurl
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /MobMediaStudiosSite/Scripts/basemvcurl
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /MobMediaStudiosSite/Scripts/baseservicesurl
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /MobMediaStudiosSite/Scripts/main

Has anyone run across this? My assumption is that a wildcard mimetype is not in place to allow the request for these files to process.

Thanks

Comment: Did this ever work for you? Maybe a fluke and an app restart would kick it back into gear.

Comment: I was able to get this working. It turns out you have to turn of Require.JS. Perhaps it has something to do with me testing on a localhost/application instead of a separate web application?

Comment: On another note, I have tested the current version with Sitefinity 7.3.5610 with assembly redirection and I am getting a javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.